# Applying convolution operation to image - PyTorch

Tags: python, pytorch

To render an image if shape 27x35 I use :

```
random_image = []
for x in range(1 , 946):
        random_image.append(random.randint(0 , 255))

random_image_arr = np.array(random_image)
matplotlib.pyplot.imshow(random_image_arr.reshape(27 , 35))
```

This generates :

[image]

I then try to apply a convolution to the image using the `torch.nn.Conv2d` :

```
conv2 = torch.nn.Conv2d(3, 18, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1)

image_d = np.asarray(random_image_arr.reshape(27 , 35))

conv2(torch.from_numpy(image_d))
```

But this displays error :

```
~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/conv.py in forward(self, input)
    299     def forward(self, input):
    300         return F.conv2d(input, self.weight, self.bias, self.stride,
--> 301                         self.padding, self.dilation, self.groups)
    302 
    303 

RuntimeError: input has less dimensions than expected
```

The shape of the input `image_d` is `(27, 35)`

Should I change the parameters of `Conv2d` in order to apply the convolution to the image ?

Update. From @McLawrence answer I have :

```
random_image = []
for x in range(1 , 946):
        random_image.append(random.randint(0 , 255))

random_image_arr = np.array(random_image)
matplotlib.pyplot.imshow(random_image_arr.reshape(27 , 35))
```

This renders image :

[image]

Applying the convolution operation :

```
conv2 = torch.nn.Conv2d(1, 18, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1)

image_d = torch.FloatTensor(np.asarray(random_image_arr.reshape(1, 1, 27 , 35))).numpy()

fc = conv2(torch.from_numpy(image_d))
```

matplotlib.pyplot.imshow(fc[0][0].data.numpy())

renders image :

[image]

Comment: @McLawrence no, just thought it may be useful to share the implementation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two problems with your code:

First, 2d convolutions in `pytorch` are [defined](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/nn.html#torch.nn.Conv2d) only for 4d tensors.
This is convenient for use in neural networks. The first dimension is the batch size while the second dimension are the channels (a RGB image for example has three channels). So you have to reshape your tensor like

```
image_d = torch.FloatTensor(np.asarray(random_image_arr.reshape(1, 1, 27 , 35)))
```

The `FloatTensor`is important here, since convolutions are not defined on the `LongTensor` which will be created automatically if your `numpy` array only includes `int`s.

Secondly, You have created a convolution with three input channels, while your image has just one channel (it is greyscale). So you have to adjust the convolution to:

```
conv2 = torch.nn.Conv2d(1, 18, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1)
```